# Rename multiple cell in a csv large file using Python csv module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I've a large CSV file. There are a lot of cells value "NIL" mentioned in different columns. I need to set the value blank. I mean those cells will return blank space.

I repeat I don't have to rename header or any specific cell. I've to rename multiple cells matching "NIL" to this " "

Answer (score 0):

If i am correct you want to handle missing data. It depends in which way you want to handle missing data. Python provides machenism to deal with such data cells.

You can either refer to [this link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html) for handling missing data.

The fillna function can “fill in” NA values with non-null data in various ways:

1. Replace NA with a scalar value:

   fillna(0)
2. Padding the value

   fillna(method='pad')
3. Dropping the column or row

   dropna(axis=0),
   dropna(axis=1),
   dropna()
4. Interpolate the data

   interpolate()
5. Replacing Values

   replace()

Comment: Data cells filled up with the string "NIL" which I need to replace with empty string.

Comment: Please try with replace() function in such case.